# Custom UITableViewCell Cell Objects Overlapping

Tags: uitableview

I have this problem where I have a custom UITableviewCell, in it there are three objects, a UIImageView and two UILabels. For some reason, my two labels overlap each other. I don't think this is a case of the cell not refreshing as the labels should be stacked, one at 0 y coordinate, the other at 18. When I log those coordinates they come out correct, but in the sim display they look like this:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?